# Empires Rise and Fall, People Come and Go

Tags: ideas

I've got this sense that everything on earth and the universe will eventually decay or end. It may take seconds, hours, years or even billion of years. Let us say for example the life span of fridges and washing machines, the decay of plutonium, and the ultimate end of the universe (the Big Rip).

Is there a concept, idea, or theory that states or tells us that this is indeed the case? And what are those?

I've already got the Second Law of Thermodynamics to begin with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about writing at all.

Comment: This might go on WorldBuilding, Philosophy, or Physics, but not here, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

As the Bard said,

Golden lads and girls all must,
As chimney-sweepers, come to dust.

*Cymbeline* Act IV, Scene 2

The whole passage is very relevant -- http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/fear-no-more/

Answer (score 0):

The feeling you are describing here is associated to the term [weltschmerz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltschmerz).

BTW How does this question relate to writing?